# A question on GCD

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $n_2>n_1>r>1$ be positive integers, let $r\neq gcd(n_i,r)=t>1$ for $i=1,2$ and let $n_1\nmid n_2$.

How do you disprove $gcd(n_1,n_2) \bmod r=gcd(n_1\bmod r,n_2\bmod r)\bmod r$?

Does $gcd(gcd(n_1\bmod r,n_2\bmod r)\bmod r,r)=t$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have your tried checking some values to see if it holds?

Comment: It looks like you already have a counterexample. So you have disproved the statement.

Comment: sorry my constraint had $r$ not divide $n_1,n_2$ and $gcd(r,n_1)=gcd(r,n_2)>1$.

Comment: Your edits seem to imply that $\gcd(n_1,r) = \gcd(n_2,r) = t > 1$. Is that what is intended?

Comment: @JohnHabert Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with the extra conditions, this is still not true. Take $r=6$, $n_1 = 16$ and $n_2 = 32$. Then $6 \neq \gcd(16,6) = \gcd(32,6) = 2 > 1$. Calculating we get $\gcd(16,32) \pmod{6} = 16 \pmod{6} \equiv 4 \pmod{6}$ and $\gcd\left(16 \pmod{6}, 32\pmod{6}\right)\pmod{6} = \gcd(4,2) \pmod{6} = 2 \pmod{6}$.

---

To deal with the extra condition of $n_1 \nmid n_2$, let $r=6$, $n_1 = 70$ and $n_2 = 80$. Then $6 \neq \gcd(70,6) = \gcd(80,6) = 2 > 1$. Calculating we get $\gcd(70,80) \pmod{6} = 10 \pmod{6} \equiv 4 \pmod{6}$ and $\gcd\left(70 \pmod{6}, 80\pmod{6}\right)\pmod{6} = \gcd(4,2) \pmod{6} = 2 \pmod{6}$.

---

In response to "$gcd(gcd(n_1\bmod r,n_2\bmod r)\bmod r,r)=t$?", the answer is no. Let $r=6$, $n_1 = 10$ and $n_2 = 22$. Then $6 \neq \gcd(10,6) = \gcd(22,6) = 2$ but $\gcd(10\pmod{6},22\pmod{6})\pmod{6} = \gcd(4,4)\pmod{6} = 4 \neq \gcd(4,6) = 2$.

Comment: Interesting answer. So is the failure because $16|32$? Is there an example where $n_1<n_2$ and $n_1$ not divide $n_2$?

Comment: $16|32$ is what I exploited to create the counterexample.

Comment: True in my experiments I do not have that scenario.

Comment: @J.A I've edited my answer to deal with the extra condition.

Comment: How did you construct this one? When does the modular equation hold though?

Comment: Just one last question added.

Comment: $16 \equiv 10 \pmod{6}$, $70 \equiv 16\pmod{6}$ and $80\equiv 32 \pmod{6}$

Comment: I added one last question. Want to know if $GCD(gcd(n_1\bmod r,n_2\bmod r)\bmod r,r)=t$?

Comment: Is the gcd $=t$?